# Tomcat 9 and Servlet API 2.5

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, tomcat9

My spring web application is using servlet api 2.5 along with spring framework 4. Its deployed in tomcat 9. Its working fine. I am not sure why tomcat is not complaining about it as it needs servlet api 4 as per documentation. Is it backward compatible or spring is doing some magic? Just for clarity We are using interfaces from servlet api 2.5  in our code which should not compile with servlet api 4. It is compiling because we are compiling with 2.5 but we are expecting it to fail at runtime in tomcat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using methods/classes that no longer exist in servlet spec 4? There isn't magic - it's downward compatible. If you tried to run, for example, AsyncEvent code in Tomcat 5.5 (servlet spec 2.4) then yes, you'd have a problem. But running old code on a new server - without using things that have totally changed or disappeared - is rarely a problem.

## **EDIT**

You said that the "old" code has:

```
Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
```

This is still valid if not best practice.  With newer compilers you may get a warning from the compiler that you are not using generics but it is still valid.  And since the Javadocs from that time say:

> Returns: an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type String array.

So your old code **must** be casting the keys as a String and the values as a String[] - just like the newer code that would be:

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
```

Both versions will compile in recent versions of the compiler though, again, you may get warnings with the code that doesn't take advantage of generics.

The key is the use of generics - the `<String, String[]>` part.  It's clearer code when using generics and the compiler can help with issues.  With the non-generics version you could have tried to cast the key in the map to any object.  It would compile but at runtime you'd likely get a `ClassCastException`.

From the perspective of Tomcat it's still returning the same thing.

Is that clearer?

Comment: HTTPServletRequest.getParameterMap() returns Map<String,Object>. This is compiling because we are compiling with 2.5 version. But i am expecting it to fail at runtime as Tomcat 9 is using 4 version and in that the abobe method return Map<String,String[]>. So does it mean tomcat at runtime deciding which version to use?

Comment: No, `HTTPServletRequest.getParameterMap()` returns a `Map` of "an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type String array."  It's simply before the advent of generics.

Comment: i am sorry i did not get this. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Map<String,Object> param=request.getParameterMap();                                                   This code works in Servlet 2.5 but i get compilation issue with servlet api 4.0 asking me to change Object to String[]. So i was expecting same thing while i am executing this code on tomcat 9 but it does not.

Comment: That is not the correct declaration - that is a bug.  Read the Javadocs and you'll see that that is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, i can understand now that it should be like this Map param=request.getParameterMap(); and later on we can check the type of the value and cast it to String[]. But i am still not sure why Tomcat is not complaining about this while executing. Is there a Spring implementation which is supporting both i.w Map<String,Object> and Map<String,String[]> OR tomcat at runtime deciding which version to use based on web.xml.

Comment: A `String[]` **is a** Object.  So nothing needs to change and Tomcat can return the same thing either way.